# Laravel 5 home page controller

Tags: php, controller, laravel-5

After login it will redirect to http://localhost/laravel/public/home

So view file location will be \resources\views\home.blade.php.

Now on this home page i'm able to get login user id

```
<?php
echo $id = Auth::id();
?>
```

now i have created controller using

```
D:\wamp\www\laravel>php artisan make:controller HomeController
```

Controller created successfully.

Now on home page i have to show some data on basis of logged in user.

In home controller if i do echo exit, but it's not working. So in which controller file i have to write code?

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your home controller

Comment: Is it just me or is this question really ambiguous?  I'm assuming you've got your route working, and your middleware set-up, you've got your view returning but **you just want to retrieve data from `Auth::user()`**?

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the user data this way

```
 {{ Auth::user()->field_name }}
```

For example:

```
{{ Auth::user()->id }}
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
{{ Auth::user()->email }}
```

Comment: Thah i already have.Thanks. I need to use controller. Because on basis of user id i have to fetch data from another table

Comment: Eloquent provides you good ways for doing it without using the controller. You may do: $user->your_table if you have defined a relationship before in their models. I strongly recommend you. Check the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

Answer (score 0):

first you may need to create a route in routes.php

```
Route::get('laravel/public/home', [
'as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'
]);
```

and then add code in your HomeController's index() function.

Answer (score 0):

In your `HomeController.php` add the below lines to make use of it.

```
use Auth;
```

So, Your `HomeController.php` will look like this

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
```

And Now, you can do `return Auth::user()->id` from your controller to return the Loggedin user's Id.

It will look like this

```
public function index()
{
return Auth::user()->id;
}
```

**Note :**

You can see the `Auth::user()->id` only if the user is get authenticated.